# UbuntuOne for windows

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, windows-7

Im very new to Ubuntu but i've been using it since I purchased a netbook and was given a disc by a friend of mine.

I am a researcher so I needed a simple but quick operating system and Ubuntu seems to do the trick.

On my home PC I use Windows and, until I upgraded to Windows 7 I had the beta for Windows.
The PC was wiped during the upgrade and now I can not find the beta!

Help me please!

Katie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice and simple one :-)
The beta has been removed from the Home page now but you can still get it from :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Windows

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can get the beta [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/windows/beta).

More info [here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Windows)